# Displaying the upload date of a python package

Tags: python, pip, python-module

I know pip freeze displays all the packages you've downloaded and their associated versions, but is there a way to display the upload dates of those packages (without manually going onto PyPI)?

Comment: It doesn’t look like `pip freeze` includes that option directly: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_freeze.html If PyPI has an API, you could probably script doing the date lookups, but that may be more trouble than doing it by hand.